# JavaScript: how to retrieve value from a method that doesn't have `return`

Tags: javascript, function, methods, pikaday

I am trying to modify an existing datepicker plug-in ([Pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday)) to display the selected date in some rendered HTML (that is rendered in the plugin).

I have identified that the following setDate method/function returns the date string I want to use, but I am unsure how to extract it and use it in my function.

The setDate method appears as:

```
 setDate: function(date, preventOnSelect)
    {
        if (!date) {
            this._d = null;

            if (this._o.field) {
                this._o.field.value = '';
                fireEvent(this._o.field, 'change', { firedBy: this });
            }

            return this.draw();
        }
        if (typeof date === 'string') {
            date = new Date(Date.parse(date));
        }
        if (!isDate(date)) {
            return;
        }

        var min = this._o.minDate,
            max = this._o.maxDate;

        if (isDate(min) && date < min) {
            date = min;
        } else if (isDate(max) && date > max) {
            date = max;
        }

        this._d = new Date(date.getTime());
        setToStartOfDay(this._d);
        this.gotoDate(this._d);

        if (this._o.field) {
            this._o.field.value = this.toString();
            fireEvent(this._o.field, 'change', { firedBy: this });
            //I want to return `this._o.field.value`
        }
        if (!preventOnSelect && typeof this._o.onSelect === 'function') {
            this._o.onSelect.call(this, this.getDate());
        }
    }
```

and I want to return `this._o.field.value`.

Would anyone know how I could grab this and use it in my function?

PS, I am coming from a PHP OOP background, so my understanding of JS OOP might be lacking, sorry. My HTML rendering function:

```
renderHeading = function(instance, c, year, month, days)
{
    var opts = instance._o;
    var html = '<div class="pika-heading">';
    html += '<h3 class="pika-heading-year">' + year + '</h3>';
    html += '<h1 class="pika-heading-date">' + opts.i18n.weekdaysShort[day] + ', ' + opts.i18n.monthsShort[month] + '</h1>';
    return html += '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I would have written something like `window.myDateProperty` in the  `if (this._o.field)` and read in the php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (this._o.field) {
            this._o.field.value = this.toString();
            window.myDateProperty = this._o.field.value;// Add your own property
            fireEvent(this._o.field, 'change', { firedBy: this });
            //I want to return `this._o.field.value`-- I wont prefer returning as that alters the library code.
        }
```

now `window.myDateProperty` containing the `this._o.field.value` will be available in the javascript files.

PS: always do the check:

```
if(window.myDateProperty){
  //use window.myDateProperty
}
```

Comment: this won't work if there are multiple elements hooked up to that setDate callback. if you want to go this way, you'll have to provide the current field's context while storing the value as a global variable. something like `window[this._o.field.fieldName] = this._o.field.value;`